# Simple way to save HTML table to SQL file?

Tags: html, sql, excel, export, html-table

I have a big list of data I need to insert into a mysql database. All tables look the same structurally. Is there any simple ways of exporting all table rows into an SQL file ready to import to a database table with the same structure?

Sounds like something that could be achieved with Javascript, but i don't know enough javascript to do it yet, and i also don't have very much time to do it. I need it within a few days.

I also have it in an excel file if it's easier that way. I've been searching but most results are for exporting SQL to html (the other way around), which i don't really need, the other results didn't really give me anything either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to phpMyAdmin, you can import a .csv file directly into your MySQL table (you can save an excel file to a .csv file in the Save As menu).

See here

http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2007/05/19/import-a-csv-file-to-mysql-via-phpmyadmin/

Your table should be exacly the same structure as your csv file, i.e. all columns in the order of your csv file.

Comment: I hadn't thought of Excel. Neat

Comment: After 5 minutes of "loading..." it gave me a syntax error. I'm one step closer though, thanks!

Comment: This is the right way to go. Albeit if you have db server access I would skip the PHP piece. Here is reference for MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Your .csv file must be perfectly formatted. Single or double quotes can break this stucture, and give you the syntax errors. You can change what the cells and lines are delimited by, but please make sure you change the settings when Importing in phpMyAdmin. It may be worth opening your .csv file in notepad and looking for obviuos formatting errors, splitting your .csv file into smaller chunks or starting off with a test file that will Import without the errors and then adding to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily with jQuery:

```
var output = [];
var temp;
var cellValues;
$('tr').each(function () {
    temp = 'INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (";
    cellValues = [];
    $(this).children().each(function () {
        cellValues.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"'); // <-- you may need to do escaping here
    });
    temp += cellValues.join(", ") + ");";
    output.push(temp);
});

console.log(output.join("\n"));
```

Comment: and send this injection monster to the server? woah

Comment: well, i'd copy it and paste it myself. Obviously this wouldn't be on a public site for anyone to use...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unix, you can use awk to convert the file with HTML table to CSV. Most database servers seem to support import from CSV

EDIT:

Even if you don't use Unix or care about awk you can open the table in your favorite text editor and Find/Replace

```
1. "<tr>" ""
2. "</tr> ""
3. "<td>" ""
4. "</td> ";"
```

Or something like that